# Suppose the function is in the form $\vec{F}(\vec{r}(t),\vec{v}(t),t)$

Tags: calculus

Suppose the function is in the form $\vec{F}(\vec{r}(t),\vec{v}(t),t)$
I want to know that What type of function is ?
$F:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R^3}$ or ....

Comment: Is $\vec{r}$ the abstract position vector or just it's representation?

Comment: @Botond $\vec{r}(t)$ is vector .

Comment: I know that. But what kind of vector is it? An "abstract thing" or just a triplet of real numbers?

Comment: @Botond a triplet of real numbers?

Comment: Is it an element of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: @Botond yeah it is element of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's assume that $\vec F$ is a real-valued vector field with three scalar components, $F_x$, $F_y$, and $F_z$, $\vec r$ is the position vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$, $\vec v$ is the velocity vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and $t$ represents time (a scalar)$.

Then, $\vec F(\vec r(t), \vec v(t), t))$ is a mapping from $\mathbb{R}^7$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$.  For example, in Cartesian coordinates we have

$$\begin{align}
 \vec F(\vec r(t), \vec v(t), t))&=\hat x  F_x(x(t),y(t),z(t), v_x(t),v_y(t),v_z(t),t)\\\\&
+\hat y  F_y(x(t),y(t),z(t), v_x(t),v_y(t),v_z(t),t)\\\\
&+\hat z  F_z(x(t),y(t),z(t), v_x(t),v_y(t),v_z(t),t)
\end{align}$$

which explicitly shows the dependence of $\vec F$ on $7$ variables.

Comment: Generally speaking, $\vec{r} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ is not always true (and it's true for the other vectors as well), because it's just a representation.

Comment: @Botond In general, you are correct.  Please note that I stated assumptions and then made a conclusion.  That said, in most applications in physics and engineering, $\vec r$ represents the position vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  If we don't make that assumption, and instead assume that $\vec r\in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $\vec v\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\vec F \in \mathbb{R}^p$, then the mapping is from $\mathbb{R}^{m+n+1}$ to $\mathbb{R}^p$.  But I suspect that the confusion lies in the fact that $\vec v(t)=\vec r'(t)$ and the OP questions whether there are truly $7$ independent variables or just $4$..

Comment: I like this answer. If I may make a distinction (because this used to confuse me with "total" derivatives i.e. chain rule stuff) that the composition function $\vec{F}(\vec{r}(t), \vec{v}(t), t)$ is a single variable function while the outside function $\vec{F}$ depends on 7 variables

Comment: @MarkViola I was not talking about the dimension, but about the concept of the "position vector". The $\mathbb{R}^3$ "form$ is just a representation, like in the linear operator - matrix case.

Comment: @botond I don't understand your point.  Just take $\vec r$ to be three variables, without regard to physical interpretation if you like.